# Why is this so slow with goroutines?

Tags: go

I posted a question with nearly the same code yesterday, asking how to make this concurrent amongst a variadic function. After it was resolved, I expected the program to run nearly the same amount of time with one generator as with 30+. It doesn't seem so.

The times I see are with one generator, about 5ms. With what's in the code below, 150ms. (For some reason, play.golang shows 0).

Why is it slower? My expectation was that, with the multiple goroutines, it would take about as long. Something to do with spinning up the goroutines?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    _ = fanIn(
        generator(4, 5, 6, 7),
        generator(1, 2, 6, 3, 7),
        generator(12, 15, 33, 40, 10),
        generator(18, 13, 20, 40, 15),
        generator(100, 200, 64000, 3121, 1237),
        generator(4, 5, 6, 7),
        generator(1, 2, 6, 3, 7),
        generator(12, 15, 33, 40, 10),
        generator(18, 13, 20, 40, 15),
        generator(100, 200, 64000, 3121, 1237),
        generator(4, 5, 6, 7),
        generator(1, 2, 6, 3, 7),
        generator(12, 15, 33, 40, 10),
        generator(18, 13, 20, 40, 15),
        generator(100, 200, 64000, 3121, 1237),
        generator(4, 5, 6, 7),
        generator(1, 2, 6, 3, 7),
        generator(12, 15, 33, 40, 10),
        generator(18, 13, 20, 40, 15),
        generator(100, 200, 64000, 3121, 1237),
        generator(4, 5, 6, 7),
        generator(1, 2, 6, 3, 7),
        generator(12, 15, 33, 40, 10),
        generator(18, 13, 20, 40, 15),
        generator(100, 200, 64000, 3121, 1237),
        generator(4, 5, 6, 7),
        generator(1, 2, 6, 3, 7),
        generator(12, 15, 33, 40, 10),
        generator(18, 13, 20, 40, 15),
        generator(100, 200, 64000, 3121, 1237),
        generator(4, 5, 6, 7),
        generator(1, 2, 6, 3, 7),
        generator(12, 15, 33, 40, 10),
        generator(18, 13, 20, 40, 15),
        generator(100, 200, 64000, 3121, 1237),
    )

    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(t))
}

func generator(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int, 10)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for _, v := range nums {
            out <- v
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func fanIn(in ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int, 10)
    wg.Add(len(in))

    go func() {
        for _, v := range in {
            go func(ch <-chan int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                for val := range ch {
                    out <- val
                }
            }(v)
        }

    }()
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

Comment: What is your Go version, and how many CPU cores do you have, for me it is less than 1ms.

Comment: I have go version go1.6.2 darwin/amd64, MBP 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5.

Comment: Also, I'm running this with 'go run' instead of installing, which I believe is the slowest. The test wasn't to make it run fast, it was to see if I can run multiple generators in the same speed. Just FYI.

Comment: `go run` doesn't make a slower executable, but it does need to compile a new one each time. You're comparing the compile times from 2 different programs. Either build both executables (or 1 with an option of some sort), or use a proper testing benchmark.

Comment: It looks to me that you're not doing anything but copying values between channels. You should know that Go's channels use locks, and that as you get more and more CPU threads running, lock contention increases. If you were doing real work this would matter much less but what you have here looks like a benchmark of the Go channel implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little difference between `go run` and `go build` (compile time):
for me `17ms` (on 2 Cores)  and `3ms` (on 8 Cores) with  `go1.7 amd64`:

difference between `go run` and `go build`:
951.0543ms-934.0535ms = **17.0008ms** (on 2 Cores)
575.3447ms-572.3914ms = **2.9533ms**  (on 8 Cores)

difference between 8 Cores and 2 Cores with `go build`:
 934.0535ms-572.3914ms = **361.6621ms**

For good benchmark statistics, use large number of samples.
try update to latest Go version ( `1.7`).

Try this working sample code, and compare your result with these outputs:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    cs := make([]<-chan int, 1000)
    for i := 0; i < len(cs); i++ {
        cs[i] = generator(rand.Perm(10000)...)
    }
    ch := fanIn(cs...)
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(t))

    is := make([]int, 0, len(ch))
    for v := range ch {
        is = append(is, v)
    }
    fmt.Println("len=", len(is))
}

func generator(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int, len(nums))
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for _, v := range nums {
            out <- v
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func fanIn(in ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int, 10)
    wg.Add(len(in))

    go func() {
        for _, v := range in {
            go func(ch <-chan int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                for val := range ch {
                    out <- val
                }
            }(v)
        }

    }()
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

output with 2 Cores ( with `go run`):

```
951.0543ms
len= 10000000
```

output with 2 Cores ( with `go build`):

```
934.0535ms
len= 10000000
```

output with 8 Cores ( with `go run`):

```
575.3447ms
len= 10000000
```

output with 8 Cores ( with `go build`):

```
572.3914ms
len= 10000000
```

Comment: @nathan-hyland I hope this helps.